# Best Sites for Simplified Instructions in Taking Wedding Photos

Tags: tips, web, wedding

Does anybody have any recommendations for Photography Sites that give you some basic yet good instructions on shooting weddings?

Answer (score 14):

Most important tip: if your friends did ask you to take photos of their wedding and you are entirely new to this kind of photography: **DO NOT DO IT**.

Really. Spare yourself and your friends (possibly they are not your friends anymore) the disappointment. Hire a professional (they are not this expensive) and take photos along with him (ask him beforehands, he'll tell you when not to distract the people/couple). Look at his style, learn from his style ... and then start looking at websites for the third or fourth wedding that you'll shoot on your own.

Comment: Interesting related article: common ways to make a first wedding a disaster http://www.lensrentals.com/news/2010.07.25/fwigtew-and-other-first-wedding-acronymss

Comment: Disappointment depends entirely on expectations. If these are sufficiently low there's no reason to expect they'll be disappointed!

Answer (score 8):

I have found the Digital Photography School site fairly decent for some tutorials and tips, here is a basic set of tips for wedding photography ... http://www.digital-photography-school.com/wedding-photography-tips-to-get-you-started

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these ideas from photographer Moshe Zusman:
http://www.bhinsights.com/content/5-tips-create-drama-your-wedding-portraits.html

Comment: awesome article.  thanks for posting the link.  +1